# Google service account authorization with JWT in Go

Tags: go

How do I authorize a service account with JWT in Go?

Answer (score 7):

Use https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/

`go get code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth`

Get your service email and your p12 private key from the Google API Console. For now it can't read p12 files so strip them to just the rsa key with openssl
`openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -nocerts -out key.pem -nodes` then delete the extra text

Then:

```
package main

import (
  "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth/jwt"
  "flag"
  "fmt"
  "http"
  "io/ioutil"
)

var (
  serviceEmail = flag.String("service_email", "", "OAuth service email.")
  keyPath      = flag.String("key_path", "key.pem", "Path to unencrypted RSA private key file.")
  scope        = flag.String("scope", "", "Space separated scopes.")
)

func fetchToken() (string, error) {
    // Read the pem file bytes for the private key.
    keyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*keyPath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    t := jwt.NewToken(*serviceEmail, *scope, keyBytes)
    c := &http.Client{}

    // Get the access token.
    o, err := t.Assert(c)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return o.AccessToken, nil
}

func main() {
  flag.Parse()
  token, err := fetchToken()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("ERROR: %v\n", err)
  } else {
    fmt.Printf("SUCCESS: %v\n", token)
  }
```

Comment: Note that code.google.com/p/goauth2 is now deprecated - it has been superseded by golang.org/x/oauth2