# Go and google calendar api

Tags: go, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

I want to rewrite in Go a PHP app that read/write events to and from my user's calendars. That app uses an API service account key looking like this: `207000******-***********@developer.gserviceaccount.com`. My PHP script also uses a binary p12 key to access the user's calendars that have granted r/w access to these credentials.

I want to reuse these credentials in my Go app. I have been googling around to find a easy Go howto, step by step kind of thing, unsuccessfully so far.

I could get the [quickstart.go](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/go) to work with a new 
client ID (it produces a list of the events from my own calendar). And I am stuck there. I need some examples and/or step by step directions.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So what you want to know how to get service account authentication to work with GO? or you want to know how to make a request in Go to Google Calendar using an access token gotten from the PHP authentication process?

Comment: I want (1) my Go app to be identified as the Google account ID used by my PHP app. The same that my users share their calendar with. This is to avoid them having to re-share their calendar with another ID. And (2) use any key to access the calendars. Sorry if this is not clear, but the whole Google API looks like black magic to me. Could get it work once with PHP using the [examples](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get) from Google, but no examples scripts yet for Go.

Comment: It is a bit like black magic until you get the hang of it.  The thing is if you are using a service account then users aren't approving anything really.  If you want access to their accounts you should probably be using Oauth2

Comment: Note: I do not have the power of Go. But do have Google API black magic powers.   How about this http://stackoverflow.com/q/15374625/1841839

Comment: I thought that I was already using Oaut2 in my PHP app. I that p12 key file not generated in the Oauth2 creation process? Anyway, what should I do to access the calendar of my users that are already shared with my Account Key `******@developer.gservice.com`? I am nowhere in that project due to my lack of knowledge of the Google API but I am tenacious!

Comment: You said uses a binary p12 that's only used with service account credentials.     You will need to switch to Oauth2 and have the user authenticate your application or stick with using service account.   Its just going to be hard IMO to keep track of who is who with that service account sharing of calendars.

Comment: Here is my article on service accounts http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/  vs Oauth2 http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/

Comment: After reading your interesting blog, I now understand that I definitely need to access my user's calendar with a Google Developer console service account. I will investigate how to do that in Go. Thanks a lot for your input. JL